# How to understand the prefix characters for the explained plan of spark sql

Tags: apache-spark

Take the following simple query as an example,which is counting the number of employees for each department.

```sql
select 
   t2.dept_name, 
   coalesce(count(t1.emp_id),0) as emp_num  
from t2 
left join t1 on t2.dept_id = t1.dept_id
group by t2.dept_name 
order by t2.dept_name
```

The physical plan is:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Sort [dept_name#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(dept_name#13 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), true, [id=#51]
   +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[dept_name#13], functions=[count(emp_id#4)], output=[dept_name#13, emp_num#16L])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(dept_name#13, 200), true, [id=#47]
         +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[dept_name#13], functions=[partial_count(emp_id#4)], output=[dept_name#13, count#21L])
            +- *(1) Project [dept_name#13, emp_id#4]
               +- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [dept_id#12], [dept_id#5], LeftOuter, BuildRight
                  :- *(1) LocalTableScan [dept_id#12, dept_name#13]
                  +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[1, int, false] as bigint))), [id=#32]
                     +- LocalTableScan [emp_id#4, dept_id#5]
```

I would ask how to understand `+-`, `:-` prefix in the above explained plan tree, Sometimes  `:`  also appears(there is a whitespace after :, sometimes this prefix appears,but not in my above case)

Thanks.

Comment: You could take a look at [Visualizing Spark Plan as UML diagram](https://github.com/keks51/spark_plan_as_uml?tab=readme-ov-file#visualizing-spark-plan-as-uml-diagram), and try to guess what those `+-` and `:-` prefixes mean, but then you need to know about UML.

Answer (score 2):

This explanation is for Spark version 3.5.0, the last version at the time of this post.

You can understand the significance of those signs by looking at the [`generateTreeString`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode.scala#L991-L1065) method in `TreeNode.scala`. The essential part is this:

```scala
  /**
   * Appends the string representation of this node and its children to the given Writer.
   *
   * The `i`-th element in `lastChildren` indicates whether the ancestor of the current node at
   * depth `i + 1` is the last child of its own parent node.  The depth of the root node is 0, and
   * `lastChildren` for the root node should be empty.
   *
   * Note that this traversal (numbering) order must be the same as [[getNodeNumbered]].
   */
  def generateTreeString(
      depth: Int,
      lastChildren: java.util.ArrayList[Boolean],
      append: String => Unit,
      verbose: Boolean,
      prefix: String = "",
      addSuffix: Boolean = false,
      maxFields: Int,
      printNodeId: Boolean,
      indent: Int = 0): Unit = {
    (0 until indent).foreach(_ => append("   "))
    if (depth > 0) {
      val iter = lastChildren.iterator
      (0 until lastChildren.size - 1).foreach { i =>
        val isLast = iter.next
        append(if (isLast) "   " else ":  ")
      }
      append(if (lastChildren.get(lastChildren.size() - 1)) "+- " else ":- ")
    }
```

From this code, we can see that:

- `+-` is used when a node is the last child of its parent node (almost all the nodes in your example tree)
- `:-` is used when a node is not the last child of its parent node

  - in the case of your `*(1) LocalTableScan` line, you see that there is another node at the same indentation level: `BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode`
- `:`  with a number of white spaces is used when there is a subtree with more than 1 node in there.

  - So if, in your case, you would add a transformation to the table with `[dept_id#12, dept_name#13]` columns, you would see that situation pop up right after the `*(1) LocalTableScan [dept_id#12, dept_name#13]` node.